# Rails 6: ActionText attached image not rendering in _blob partial template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

I'm currently working on a Rails 6 application in which I'm using cloduinary for hosting the images. I have a model with `rich_text_content`.

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_rich_text :content
end
```

When I add an image from the rich text editor and try to render the image the browser doesn't render the attach image.

views/questions/show.html.erb

```
<div class="border-t-2 border-gray-600 text-2xl m-auto w-4/5">
    <div class="h-56 my-8">
      <%= @question.content %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The `show.html.erb` template is only displaying the text content not the attachment image in the `@question.content` so when there is an `embeds_blob` the `_blob.html.erb` is not displaying the image.

```
<figure class="attachment attachment--<%= blob.representable? ? "preview" : "file" %> attachment--<%= blob.filename.extension %>">
  <% if blob.representable? %>
      <div class="max-w-xl mx-auto rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
        <%= cl_image_tag(blob.key, format: :jpg )%>
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
          <figcaption class="attachment__caption">
            <% if caption = blob.try(:caption) %>
              <%= caption %>
            <% else %>
              <div class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2">
                <span class="attachment__name"><%= blob.filename %></span>
                <span class="attachment__size"><%= number_to_human_size blob.byte_size %></span>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </figcaption>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</figure>
```

The `cl_image_tag(blob.key, format: :jpg)` should be rendering the attachment file but it does not as shown in the image below
[image]

However if I were to comment everything down and only have the following line. `<%= cl_image_tag(blob.key, format: :jpg )%>`. The image is render without the HTML structure from the `_blob.html.erb`.
[image]

Why is the `_blob.html.erb` not rendering the attach image coming from Cloudinary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably already know, the `blob.representable?` method call in the partial returns `false`.

If you look at the source code of [`representable?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob/representable.rb#L93) which in turn calls [`variable?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob/representable.rb#L40), you can see the [content types](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/engine.rb#L31-L42) it checks don't include `image/heic`. You could configure to include it as documented [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-storage).

> `config.active_storage.variable_content_types` accepts an array of strings indicating the content types that Active Storage can transform through ImageMagick. The default is `%w(image/png image/gif image/jpg image/jpeg image/pjpeg image/tiff image/bmp image/vnd.adobe.photoshop image/vnd.microsoft.icon image/webp)`

Once you include `image/heic` and restart the application, the image should show up.

**Note**: The above links point to the `master` branch of [rails](https://github.com/rails/rails). You might want to select the right tag depending on the rails version you're using.

Hope this helps.